# How do I take down vehicles without using the Batmobile?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

To earn the *Real Deal* trophy, I have to

> [T]akedown 20 moving cars without using the Batmobile.

**How do I take down a moving car without using the Batmobile?**

Answer (score 6):

It's simple really, two ways to do it.

1. Stand in the middle of the road and wait for a car to come by.  They'll try to run you over.  As they do so, you will have the opportunity to counter when they are close.  Batman will shoot explosive gel onto the car and cause them to crash.

   You can see this in this at around the 0:12 second mark of this video.
2. When gliding, build up enough speed and glide above a moving car.  When close enough, you can press your attack button to attack the car to cause them to crash.